# Azure AD Graph API - Get client secret from registered apps

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I've programmatically registered a web application in WAAD through POST HTTP Request. The HTTP response returns the client Id however am unable to get the client secret. Is there a way from Graph API could get the client secret for the registered apps.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is not supported. But you can add extra one client secret and both will be valid.